# What is the interface/property in ArcObjects that corresponds to a layer's dataSource property in arcpy?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, arcpy

I am trying to get the "Catalog Path" of a Feature Layer's data source in the table of contents of ArcMap using ArcObjects. This is very straightforward in arcpy but seemingly not so much in ArcObjects.

In arcpy, the [Layer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Layer/00s300000008000000/).dataSource property returns the "Catalog Path" of the layer. For example, for an SDE feature class in a feature dataset, it returns something like:

`Database Connections\MyConnection.sde\SDE.MyFeatureDataset\SDE.MyFeatureClass`

The help says that the `dataSource` property is just the `workspacePath` and `datasetName` properties combined, but this is not exactly true. For one, the `workspacePath` property expands the "Database Connections" shortcut, and secondly it does not include the feature dataset name. Thus `workspacePath` returns something like:

`c:\Documents and Settings\user\Application Data\ESRI\Desktop10.0\ArcCatalog\MyConnection.sde`

Incidentally this is also the value returned by IWorkspaceName.PathName.

So is there an ArcObjects property that corresponds directly to the `Layer.dataSource` property, or is additional logic needed to build the same "Catalog Path" from the available ArcObjects interfaces?

Comment: Did you try using IGpUtilities2.MakeGP value, then use [GetUnQualifiedCatalogPath](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/GetUnQualifiedCatalogPath_Method/002n00000478000000/)?  I find this [God Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object) hard to comprehend sometimes.

Comment: I sure hadn't! Using [MakeGPValueFromObject](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/MakeGPValueFromObject_Method/002n00000482000000/) on the `IFeatureLayer` object and passing that to GetUnQualifiedCatalogPath just returned the the short name of the feature class, i.e. `SDE.MyFeatureClass`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Kirk's comment got me close enough to figure it out. Thanks!

1. Send the layer to [IGPUtilities.MakeGPLayerFromLayer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/MakeGPLayerFromLayer_Method/002n0000047z000000/).
2. Get the [DataElement](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IDataElement_Interface/002500000132000000/) from the GPLayer
3. Return the [DataElement.CatalogPath](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/CatalogPath_Property/00250000013t000000/) value